# How to use Vuetify grid system to create both a sidebar and a navbar?

Tags: vue.js, navbar, vuetify.js, sidebar, grid-system

I'm trying to create a background using Vuetify which has both a sidebar and navbar. It should look like this:

[image]

At the moment I've created the sidebar with v-navigation-drawer, however I can't get the navbar to go in the right place. How can I add the navbar to the following code so it looks like the image above?

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-navigation-drawer
            color="#09151E"
            permanent
            expand-on-hover
        >
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list nav dense>
                <v-list-item link href="#">
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                        <v-icon color="white" small>mdi-lightbulb</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-list-item-title class="title">Blue</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-card>Navbar</v-card>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

I know that writing v-card below isn't how it should be written, but using v-row and v-col makes whitespace appear around the corners of the page and doesn't really look good

Comment: below the v-navigation-drawer, it's just a simple v-card at the moment with a title 'Name' - writing v-card like this isn't how it should be written, but using v-row and v-col makes whitespace appear around the page and doesn't really look good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is:

- Create a `v-app-bar` or a `v-toolbar` component
- Add `app` prop to your `v-navigation-drawer`

#### Demo: https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/GRpQqpG?editors=1010

```html
<v-app-bar app>
  Title
</v-app-bar>

<v-navigation-drawer
  color="#09151E"
  permanent
  expand-on-hover
  app
>
...
```

You can add `clipped-left` prop to the `app-bar` if you want it to appear behind the `navigation-drawer` instead of being next to it.

Comment: Is there a way to put it behind the navigation drawer? Or next to it? at the moment it spans across the entire page but it also covers the contents of the navigation-drawer

Comment: @Beginner_Hello are you doing exactly what I suggested? It should be next to the navigation-drawer. See the demo

Comment: It works! I didn't app the prop app to the v-navigation-drawer previously and that's why it wasn't displaying

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an 'v-app-bar' with `app` prop before the 'v-navigation-drawer'. Remove the `permanent` prop, and add `app` prop to the navigation-drawer..

```
   <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-app-bar
          app
          color="yellow"
        >
          <v-toolbar-title>Navbar</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      </v-app-bar>
      <v-navigation-drawer
            app
            color="#09151E"
            expand-on-hover>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list nav dense>
                ...
            </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
      <v-content>
          ...
      </v-content>
   </v-app>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/WSCWC3Xy1c)